# Oracle 11g Listener not working

Tags: oracle

The listener on my Oracle 11g instance is no longer working.

I tried to start it but that doesn't work.

There are no Linux processes for the listener:

```
> lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on 16-NOV-2011 10:55:08

Copyright (c) 1991, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
System parameter file is 
    /u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to 
    /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle/listener/alert/log.xml
Error listening on: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PARTIAL=yes)(QUEUESIZE=1))
No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)
    (HOST=oracle.Domain.com)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00527: Protocol Adapter not loadable


Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

I tried to delete it via `netca`, and make another one but the problem remains...

My Environment variables are properly set.

```
> tnsping oracle.Domain.com 1521

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - 
    Production on 16-NOV-2011 10:56:47

Copyright (c) 1997, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=
    (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
    (HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener"
```

the alert log in XML:

```
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.236+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.237+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle1/listener/alert/log.xml
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.237+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    Trace information written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle1/listener/trace/ora_11850_47802449326800.trc
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.237+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    Trace level is currently 0
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.237+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.238+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    Started with pid=11850
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.239+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle.Domain.com)(PORT=1521)))
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.239+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    Error listening on: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PARTIAL=yes)(QUEUESIZE=1))
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.239+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle.Domain.com)(PORT=1521)))
  </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2011-11-16T10:55:08.239+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='oracle.Domain.com'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
  <txt>
    TNS-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable
    TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
    TNS-00527: Protocol Adapter not loadable

  </txt>
</msg>
```

Hi, I tried using a sample `listener.ora`, but got the same error, the file is not ignored it just doesn't work.

There's no listener process, I need to have a process like that, I suppose :

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit
```

I see nothing on the 1521 port :

```
netstat |grep 1521
```

By the way, I have not upgraded from Oracle 10g to Oracle 11g.

Comment: Are you *really* `oracle.domain.com`?

Comment: no I can't put the real one. I can ping the real one and he is on /etc/hosts

Comment: Post your `listener.ora` please

Comment: LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle.domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    )

Comment: I don't see any reference to `PROTOCOL=ipc` there?

Comment: yeah i deleted it , same error with or without... I remade one : LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle.domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

Comment: That works for me (using `127.0.0.1` instead of `oracle.domain.com`). There must be something wrong with your Oracle install. The documentation says for `ORA-12557` *For further details, turn on tracing and reexecute the operation. The trace file will include the name of the shared library (or DLL) that could not be loaded.*

Comment: I got the same error with 127.0.0.1 instead of the oracle domain. And it worked several months, it's not a recent installation. Anyway thanks for you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message means that one (or more) of the shared libraries required for TCP communications to work could not be loaded, perhaps due to o/s package updates? or it can mean that the /tmp/.oracle directory is not writeable by the oracle user (or doesn't exist perhaps because someone did some 'housekeeping' on /tmp . In either case tracing the listener at level 16 as Gaius suggested should reveal the issue.

Comment: He is here : /var/yp/tmp/.oracle 
srwxrwxrwx 1 oracle oinstall 0 Mar  2  2011 s#16428.1
srwxrwxrwx 1 oracle oinstall 0 Mar  2  2011 s#16428.2
srwxrwxrwx 1 oracle oinstall 0 Mar  2  2011 sEXTPROC1521 I'm trying putting lvl16 tracing. Thx

Comment: permissions problems on temporary directory thx. You're good. /var/tmp/.oracle

Comment: chmod 1777 /tmp/.oracle